# In Emacs, how to disable auto-fill-paragraph mode when in php-mode?

Tags: emacs, automation, autofill

Normally, I need to enable the auto-fill-mode, so I have it turned on in .emacs.  But when editting PHP in php-mode, I'd like to not use auto-fill-mode.  Is there way to set it in .emacs such that when I'm in PHP mode, the auto-fill-paragraph mode is automatically turned off and when I leave php-mode, it's automatically turned on, barring other overriding?

Update: a closer examination of the `.emacs` revealed that auto-fill is set up by

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(column-number-mode t)
  ...
  '(text-mode-hook (quote (turn-on-auto-fill text-mode-hook-identify)))
  ...)
```

Comment: `auto-fill-mode` doesn't look like it's global, so you have probably set that to be global somewhere in your user customization files.  The easiest way I can think of to control its behavior is to put in an exception to the function that turns on `auto-fill-mode` (i.e., excluding `php-mode`) (or create such a function), or simply use it as a buffer-local minor-mode that is enabled with major-mode hooks that you normally use.  The docs state that it is a buffer-local minor-mode:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html

Comment: If it's an inheriting issue (e.g., `php-mode` is borrowing another major-mode) instead of a global setting issue, then perhaps you could try something like:  `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))`  The inheriting issue is one of the reasons that I set up my own text-mode that is distinct from the stock version -- i.e., so that other major modes don't inherit some text-mode settings.  `-1` (negative integer) turns off a minor-mode.

Comment: @lawlist Could you give your comment as a proper answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some major-modes inherit certain settings from other modes (e.g., `text-mode` is used by many popular major modes).  The following code snippet can be used to disable a feature for a particular major-mode using its mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (auto-fill-mode -1) ))
```

It is sometimes helpful to check and see whether a particular feature has been enabled globally or locally, which in turn can give a clue as to whether that feature has been inherited by a major mode.  In this case, the documentation for `auto-fill-mode` states as follows -- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html:

"*Auto Fill mode is a buffer-local minor mode (see Minor Modes) in which lines are broken automatically when they become too wide. Breaking happens only when you type a `<SPC>` or `<RET>`.*"